# Prove that $g \mapsto g^a$ is a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

"Prove that $g \mapsto g^a$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ that is prime to the group order is a Permutation on any finite group G."

Can somebody please help me?

My idea was to show that $g,h \in G$ with $g^a=h^a$ implies $g=h$, but I struggle to show that.

Comment: You can't prove it because it's not true. What about squaring in the two element group? Are you sure you have all the hypotheses?

Comment: Wait...missed one argument: 

a has to be prime to the group order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the order of $G$. SInce $(n,a)=1$, by Bezout's lemma there are $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $sn+ta=1$.

Notice the map $h\mapsto h^{t}$ is the inverse of the provided map in the problem. To see that notice that
\begin{align*}
(g^a)^t&=g^{at}\\
&=g^{at}g^{sn} \quad\quad\text{(since $g^n=1$)}\\
&=g^{at+sn}\\
&=g.
\end{align*}
The other way around compostion give you similar result.